# How to Store Array in Oracle Database Table?

Tags: arrays, angular, oracle, asp.net-core

Hi guys i am learning Angular,
in Video Tutorial they have used firebase as backend
but now i want to create WebAPI in asp.net core to fetch and store data using oracle DB

This is my firebase database layout and
**i am creating following column in Oracle DB to store data - name,description,imagepath,ingredients**  [image: Firebase Database layout]

**My Question is How to Store Multiple ingredients in Table?? and
Whats is Table Structure??**

Model Created in Angular

```
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/imgredient.model';
export class RecipeModal {

public name: string;
public description: string;
public imagepath: string;
public ingredients: Ingredient[];

constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagepath: string, ing: Ingredient[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.imagepath = imagepath;
    this.ingredients = ing;
}

}
```

Please Help

Comment: Your best bet is probably to not storing arrays at all. Go the correct relational way instead. Create a linking table between recipes and ingredients.

Comment: Means Do i need to create two table ?? recipes  and ingredients ?? how to store and retrive values for single Recipe ? can you please Help

Comment: Three tables, one for recipes, one for ingredients (in general, not per recipe) and one linking them both together. In the linking table you will have the recipe ID, the ingredient ID and the amount.

Comment: what to do when there's multiple ingredients  for single recipe, how to store that with recipe ID

Comment: That would be multiple row, all with the same recipe ID but different ingrediant ID. Maybe you should search for some tutorial on relational database design to learn the basics.